# Helm chart - Running only selected deployment files

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm charts. I have 12-14 yaml files in my helm template folder.

With helm install commands, all the files will be installed and pods will be started. It will be run in one go.

Is there any way in Helm if I can run only selected yaml files and only those pods will be up from command line. or any change in folder structure needs to be done

Comment: Yes, you may add condition each files and —set value to enable whic you want to run while install or update, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I also came across similar scenario and helm template commands' following option did the job. Used kubectl apply command on the generated file

> -s, --show-only stringArray

Just be cautious about the path of yaml file that you will pass to -s option. It's relative to the folder of the helm directory that you passed as another param

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can install only part of the Helm Chart. However, you can always execute `helm template` and then use `kubectl apply -f` to apply only the files you're interested in.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what helm template does? What is the entire command for this

Comment: It will create Kubernetes configuration out of Helm templates.